# Run jar file in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, cmd, jar, cd

I am new to Java programming. Using eclipse for coding. I want to execute JarFile.jar. Following code works fine when placing JarFile.jar inside the same directory where the project is created.

```
public class CmdTest2
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        final String dosCommand = "java -jar \"D:\\Java_codes\\CmdTest2\JarFile.jar\" 
        try
        {
            final Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(dosCommand);
            final InputStream in = process.getInputStream();
            int ch;
            while((ch = in.read()) != -1)
            {
                System.out.print((char)ch);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

But I want to execute the jar file from any other directory (say E:\Test\JarFile.jar). How can I do that? (i.e. changing directory through as well as triggering jar file).

In continuation to above pl. let me know how to run MS-DOS commands through Java.

Comment: You can pass the location of the jar file as an argument and then read this argument in your program.

when you call "java CmdTest2 E:\Test\JarFile.jar" you can then use 
final String dosCommand = args[0]; to read the jar's location dynamically.

Comment: And just for the record: you understand that you don't necessarily need to **run** a JAR in a new process - you could as well just call its main method directly?!

Comment: grateful if you pl. edit my code & show how to "pass the location of the jar file as an argument and then read this argument in your program" as suggested.

Comment: if you read my comment you can see that I already answered that.

if you use eclipse to run CmdTest2, google around to find out how to add arguments while running the program. As an argument, you can input the jar's location and then use 

    **final String dosCommand = args[0];** to read that location instead of putting it statically in your program as you do right now (.final String dosCommand = "java -jar \"D:\\Java_codes\\CmdTest2\JarFile.jar\" )